# Small live preview of FabricJS canvas in another canvas element

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an image board utilizing the excellent FabricJS library.  I am attempting to create some sort of a "keyhole" view "preview" on another canvas that is on the page, copying a small section of the fabricJS canvas, and displaying it on the second canvas using `context.drawImage()`

```
preview_canvas_context.drawImage(fabric.lowerCanvasEl, x,y, ...)
```

This works great!  My issue is ghosting from the copied image.  I'm not sure what fancy stuff FabricJS is doing in the background, but if I have some blank space behind an image or object on the fabric canvas, (or I reach the edge of the canvas) the copied image smears as illustrated in the following screen capture:

[image: screencap]

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a background image or color on the canvas prevents this issue from occurring.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
});
```

I still get image smearing when I leave the outside perimeters, but that is expected and preventable by setting bounds that the viewport object cannot leave.